# Why does the size of the icons change when I lower the screen resolution?

Tags: windows-10, resolution

The icons look blurry because of stretching probably, but I was not able to find a more in-depth explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Your display has fixed physical dimensions, so changing resolution changes physical size of pixels. Icons have fixed size measured in pixels, so when pixels grow, icons grow too.

LCD displays have a native resolution, ie. a number of actual physical pixels. When you're forcing LCD to work at a different resolution, it interpolates, ie. tries to approximate lower resolution using its denser, more numerous pixels. The bluriness is caused by boundaries of pixels your system is trying to display not matching boundaries of physical pixels.

Comment: Change your scale and text size instead of resolution to make things on screen look clearer. This works very well.